# How to have WordPress use a custom single.php template if the post is in a specific category OR its children?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a standard single.php that will be used by most posts on this website I am working on, but for a specific category and its subcategories, I want to use a custom single.php. How do I do that? I know the logic behind what I want, I'm just not sure how to write it.

Here is the code I am using but it isn't working:

```
<?php

$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category('2,6,7,8') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-blog.php'); } 

else {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-default.php');

}

?>
```

Cat IDs 6, 7 and 8 are subcats of Cat ID 2.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks,

Cynthia

Comment: This is much too broad to be answered here, as it is not clear from your question what is preventing you from doing what you want.  Have you made an attempt at implementing this logic?  If so, can you share the code and what problems you are encountering?  SO is really not intended to be a "teach me how to write code" website, and that is how this question is coming across.

Comment: What about something like what's one this page? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84537/how-do-i-create-a-single-php-for-a-specific-category

Comment: I know how to create unique iterations of single.php and how to name them so that Cat A uses single-cata.php, Cat B uses single-catb.php, etc... What I am trying to do is have Cat A and all of it's child subcategories use single-cata.php.

Comment: Sorry I edited my OP to include my code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to filter [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) or even better [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template). I'm leaving the `has_category()` conditional as hard-coded, but you *could* do something to [get the top-level category](http://alex.leonard.ie/2011/04/20/wordpress-get-id-of-top-level-parent-category/) and always test that instead.

**EDIT** now using [`post_is_in_descendant_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#post_is_in_descendant_category_function) from a codex example. Note, this isn't a built-in WordPress function so you need to include it in your plugin/theme.

**EDIT #2** Use [`locate_template()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) to ensure that the file is really there.

```
function get_custom_category_template($single_template) {

     if ( in_category( 'blog' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 2 ) ) {
          $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single-blog.php' ) );
          if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            $single_template = $new_template ;
          }
     }
     return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_category_template' );

/* Checks if a category is a descendant of another category */

if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
    function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
        foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
            // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
            if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote because your suggestion point me in the right direction in a round about sort of way :) Thank you!

Comment: Cool. I would still consider merging this code with your new `post_is_in_descendant_category ()` function. Then you only need `single.php` and `single-blog.php` and not an extra `single-default.php`.

Comment: You're right - I can see where that would make for neater (e.g. more organized) functionality. I'll give it a go and see if I can make it work that way as well.

Comment: I've just edited the code to use the `post_is_in_descendant_category()` function, which should help.

Comment: You should use `locate_template` to first check whether the template exist and then include it. Your code will fail dramatically if the template is not found as it stands. You should also have a fallback if `locate_template()` return false to avoid failure/bugs

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You can go for `single-[post-type].php`.

Read more about [The Template File Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: `category-[slug].php` is used on the category archive page, not the single post pages. Brush up on that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! helgatheviking's suggestion about the top-level category got me thinking about ancestor and descendant categories. From there I discovered the `post_is_in_descendant_category` function.

After putting the following function in my functions.php:

```
/* Checks if a category is a descendant of another category */

if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
    function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
        foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
            // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
            if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I figured out how to modify my original category query and template assignment like this:

```
<?php

$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category( 'blog' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 2 ) ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-blog.php'); } 

else {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-default.php');

}

?>
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to assist. I appreciate it a lot!